# How to record application using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record this site "https://login.salesforce.com/". But I don't know how to record it, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not salesforce support website.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and the easiest way of recording a JMeter Test is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

1. From JMeter main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create` - it will create a good [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) suitable for recording
2. Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
3. Configure your browser to use the host where JMeter is running (in majority of cases it is `localhost`) and use `8888` as a proxy port
4. Open the desired URL in your browser. If your application uses HTTPS protocol you will see a warning regarding connection not being secure - ignore it, JMeter uses self-signed automatically generated certificate in order to be able to decrypt and record HTTPS requests
5. Observe recorded requests details under `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder -> View Results Tree` and captured [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

   [image: Salesforce recording]

---

References:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [Apache JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: I am getting blank web page in IE browser while trying to record.

Comment: screenshot:   http://prntscr.com/d3bofr

Comment: When try record in Mozilla browser, getting this error                             screen shot:       http://prntscr.com/d3bp3q

Comment: Click "Advanced", then "Add Exception", then "Confirm Security Exception". BTW, some people find [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) easier to use

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for sharing your valuable wisdom. I got the solution.